# How to display nested list of lists with AngularFire2

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am trying to display a list of 'stations' and within each 'station' returned, a list of 'projects' currently at that 'station'.  Using angularfire2 snapshotChanges I can easily get the list of stations along with the metadata associated.  Then I'm getting the 'stationName' and using that in another query to get the projects associated with that station. Then in nested ngFor loops I'm displaying the stations and ideally the associated projects, however they don't show up and I'm not sure why.  In the console I can see the projects associated as the loop fetches them.  I think I'm missing something obvious, any help would be great.

desired effect:

```
station 1
 - project 1, project 3, project 5

station 2
 - project 2, project 6

station 3
 - project 4, project 7, project 8

etc.
```

firestore queries:

```
    this.shopsCollection = afs.collection('stations', ref => ref.orderBy('StationtName'));
    this.shops = this.shopsCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Shop;
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;

        this.queues = this.afs.collection('projects', ref => ref.where('station', '==', data.StationtName)).valueChanges().subscribe(data=>{
          console.log(data);
         })
console.log(data.StationtName);
        return { id, ...data };
      }))

    );
```

html:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let shop of shops | async">
       <ion-button>{{shop.StationtName}}</ion-button>

            <div *ngFor="let queue of queues | async">
                 {{queue.SKU}}
            </div>  

    </li>
</ul>
```

this particular setup results in the following error:

```
Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
```

any help greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try removing the | async pipe on the queue observable, as you are already subscribing in the component, you do not need to do in the template.

HTH

Comment: No, that gives me another error, cant remember which one.  I think the problem is my json structure, I am somehow ending up with an array of objects, or an array of arrays.

Comment: Another way would be to transform each station and add an object e.g. queues to each station (e.g. shop in your example). You can do this via a Map. This url was very helpful to me in achieving this and making the code more streamlined https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/firestore-joins-similar-to-sql/